# Android - load Byte[] into imageview with picasso

Tags: android, parse-platform, picasso

I'm using Picasso library and Parse.com for my App
I download the image via parse doc into Byte Array.

How can i show it into imageview with Picasso?
Picasso doesn't accept Byte in load().

```
file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
           if (e == null) {

              Picasso.with(this)
                     .load(data)
                     .into(wallpaper);

            } else {

            }
     }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you download the image using Picasso itself? You could pass the URL in `.load(URL)` and it'll download and display for you.

Or you can convert the `byte[]` to `Bitmap` and then pass it to `.load(Bitmap)`.

Comment: because in need percent and picasso doesn't have any percent method for progressbar. and picasso doesn't accept Bitmap

Comment: You are right, Picasso doesn't accept `Bitmap`. In that case you could set the `Bitmap` directly to your `ImageView` using `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`.

Comment: 1. you don't always have an url, but just a base64 2. there's no .load(bitmap)